# Input Delay On The "@ / ' " Key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Bit of a weird one, my "@/'" key has about a 1.5 second delay when attempting to use the key. It has to be held down for the 1.5 seconds and then it will repeat the character as if you were holding the key down.

The weird thing is that the issue persists over multiple keyboards, USB ports you name it, it's still there. Leading me to think it is a software issue. I have tried uninstalling the keyboard drivers through device manager and now I'm stumped.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Strange conclusion to draw if it persists over multiple hardware variations.

Comment: @Tetsujin My conclusion? Ah, Apologies I meant a software issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it persists over multiple keyboards (and they are different brand/model keyboards) then it is unlikely to be the drivers.

The most likely thing is a program using it as a shortcut key.  Go through your recently installed programs and investigate their shortcut keys.